# calculate the sum of two columns category

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have 2 tables :

```
1.  Table Master(Vehicle,Vehicle_Color) :

Vehicle      Vehicle_Color
---------------------------
Car          Black
Car          Yellow
Car          White   
Car          Orange
motorcyle    Black
motorcyle    Yellow
motorcyle    White
motorcyle    Orange

2.  Table Data(Name,Vehicle,Vehicle_Color)  :

Name    Vehicle     Vehicle_Color
-----------------------------------
 Ony    motorcycle  white
Galih   motorcycle  white
Zening  motorcycle  black
 Lia    motorcycle  yellow
 Tika   motorcycle  yellow
Fredy   car         black
Kenzy   car         white
Arka    car         white
Nugraha car         white
```

I want to select vehicle , vehicle_color and  count the number of vehicles and the color

```
 query :

 select vehicle,vehicle_color,(.....) as number 
 from Master left join data on ....
```

result like this

```
Vehicle      Vehicle_Color    Number
--------------------------------------
Car          Black               1
Car          Yellow              0
Car          White               3
Car          Orange              0
motorcyle    Black               1
motorcyle    Yellow              2
motorcyle    White               2
motorcyle    Orange              0
```

is there any suggestion, to create query?
Tq..

Comment: Tq FaceOfJock , :D sometimes i use language interpreter ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join both tables via columns: `vehicle` and `vehicle_color` using `LEFT JOIN` so all record on table `master` will be shown on the result list.

```
SELECT  a.vehicle,
        a.vehicle_color,
        COUNT(b.vehicle) Number
FROM    master a
        LEFT JOIN data b
            ON a.vehicle = b.vehicle AND
                a.vehicle_color = b.vehicle_color
GROUP   BY a.vehicle,
           a.vehicle_color
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be45a/2)

Comment: please find the solution of my problem
thank you very much good friends ..491243 :)